# Web.Config issue

Tags: asp.net, web-config

i have a two webservers, REMOTE and LOCAL. I have multiple projects of which some are hosted on REMOTE, some on LOCAL and some on both. I have a problem configuring the following situation:

```
http://REMOTE/                   << contains 'main project'
http://REMOTE/doubleproject/     << contains 'doubleproject'
http://LOCAL/                    << contains 'doubleproject'
```

All projects have the following entry in their Web.Config.

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" 
    type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, 
          System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
          PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
</configuration>
```

**However, the versions numbers differ. 'main project' uses version 1.1, while 'doubleproject' uses version 3.5. I receive an error on the REMOTE server:**

*'Section or group name 'system.web.extensions' is already defined. Updates to this may only occur at the configuration level where it is defined.*'

- I cannot remove the entry in 'doubleproject' because of usage on http://LOCAL
- I cannot use < clear /> or < remove name="" />, mainly because it doesn't work :-), secondly because clear/remove aren't allowed in < configSections /> after .NET 1.1
- I cannot change version to 3.5 in 'main project' and remove the entries in 'doubleproject' because of usage on http://LOCAL

***Suggestions for config or a solution anyone? Thanks!***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reported this issue as a bug to Microsoft.
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=434335

Answer (score 0):

Is your subdirectory set up as a seperate application in IIS? Adding it as a seperate application may remove the dependency on the parent configSection.

Comment: Yes it is setup as a seperate application, and this does not remove the dependency...